# rhel + parted failed after increasing OS VM disk and rescan

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, fdisk, parted

we have VM rhel machine version 7.6

example from lsblk

```
lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                8:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2             8:2    0  39.5G  0 part
│ ├─VG-RHEL_root 253:0    0  40.9G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─VG-RHEL_swap 253:1    0   7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─VG-RHEL_var  253:2    0 100.9G  0 lvm  /var
└─sda3             8:3    0   110G  0 part
  ├─VG-RHEL_root 253:0    0  40.9G  0 lvm  /
  └─VG-RHEL_var  253:2    0 100.9G  0 lvm  /var
```

before using parted

we increase the OS disk from vsphare client from 200G to 300G

then we rescan the sda disk and we get from lsblk 300 instead of previous 200G

now we want to use parted

but we get the following

```
  parted /dev/sda  resizepart 2 100%
Usage: parted [OPTION]... [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]...]...]
Apply COMMANDs with PARAMETERS to DEVICE.  If no COMMAND(s) are given, run in
interactive mode.
 
OPTIONs:
  -h, --help                      displays this help message
  -l, --list                      lists partition layout on all block devices
  -m, --machine                   displays machine parseable output
  -s, --script                    never prompts for user intervention
  -v, --version                   displays the version
  -a, --align=[none|cyl|min|opt]  alignment for new partitions
```

what could be wrong here?

Comment: The `100%` is not supported. You need to use the new `end` position or omit it to maximize the size of the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 2
```

Unfortunately the free space is after `sda3` partition and you can increase `sda2` after you move `sda3` towards the end of the disk. If you can shut down the VM, boot it from a [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) iso image and resize it with gparted

The syntax is: `resizepart partition end` See the [parted man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#resizepart) for details.

Alternatively, you can also add space the the LVM volume group by:

- creating an extended partition
- inside the extended partition, create a logical partition of type LVM
- use `pvcreate` to create a LVM disk label on the logical partition. This will be your new LVM physical volume
- use `vgextend` to add the LVM physical volume to the LVM volume group
- use `lvextend --resizefs` to resize the logical volume and the file system that is on top of it.

I wrote a script to help me with resizing of the block devices: https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/vol_resize.sh
It is just preparing the commands to run, not doing any changes.

Comment: so do you think by replacing 100% to "end" it will succeeded ?

Comment: no. You just need to remove "100%", not replace it with anything.

Comment: we perform the parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 2 , and we get the same errors

Comment: You need to add the extended partition, then logical one, create PV, then add the PV to VG, then increase the LV. Or you can move sda3 to the end of the disk with GParted Live.

Comment: so you  mean to add sda4 ? , in that case when using fdisk can we automate the fdisk process with sda4 creation ?

Comment: Best is to create another disk that you attach to the VM and use only LVM disk label. No MS-DOS or GPT partition table.

Comment: You can add sda4 as extended partition and inside sda5 as logical partition